# Mysql combination query logic

Tags: mysql

I have a table name **task** that contain Name and ID. user work with different different ID. 
I want those user name If user work for both ID 6 and 0 or User work for both ID 6 or 1.

```
Name    | ID
========|======
Vivek   | 6
Vivek   | 0
Vivek   | 1
Sumit   | 1
Sumit   | 0
Anshul  | 6
Anshul  | 1
Gourav  | 1
Gourav  | 0
Gourav  | 6
Neha    | 6
```

According to my question I want answer will be

## Name

Vivek
Anshul
Gourav

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name
  FROM task
 WHERE ID IN ( 6,1) 
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
UNION   
SELECT Name
  FROM task
WHERE ID IN ( 6,0 ) 
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM user
WHERE id in (6,0)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) >= 2

UNION

SELECT name
FROM user
WHERE id in (6,1)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `group by` and check `count()` like

```
select Name
from task
where id in (6,1)
group by name
having count(id) = 2
```

Comment: This won't return the users with ids 6 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `name` 
FROM `task` 
WHERE (`id` = 1 AND `id`= 6) OR (`id` = 0 AND `id`= 6)
GROUP BY `name` ;
```